# Column/row locking feature in primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces

I am looking for Column/rows locking functionality in prime-faces data-table.

For Example:  If Data table has 10 rows and 20 columns and when we scroll data table then only 8 rows and 15 columns should scroll vertically and horizontally respectively.

It means, we have locked starting 2 rows and 5 columns of data-table.

Please let me know if such functionality is available in prime-faces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such option , but you vote on the following issue...

[Issue 366:     FixedColumns and FixedRows for DataTable](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=366)

---

**Update**

Row freeze / lock was implemented today , see here

[Issue 5046:   Frozen Rows for Scrollable DataTable : **Status: Fixed**](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5046)

Comment: Sounds like an important feature

Answer (score 0):

only rows are able to lock with the attribute frozenRows="5" , but for locking column, primefaces are yet to develop something like "frozenColumns"